# How to get information in jquery function from the php file

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, json

My question is how to get an db information (in my case points just a number) from the php file to the jquery ajax script so here is my jquery:

```
function rate_down(id) { 
    var id = id;
//submit data to php script

    var data = {
      "id": id,
    };

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "rating.php",
      data: data,
      success: function(response) {

      var currentValue = /* here i want to put the db number */
      var newValue = +currentValue - 1;
      $("#points_"+id).text(newValue);




      },
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert(errorThrown);
      } 
    });
};
```

And I want my raiting.php. I'm not sure if I should post it because its useless but here is my mysql query in raiting.php:

```
$pic_id = (int) $_REQUEST['id'];
mysql_query = mysql_query"SELECT points FROM `photos` WHERE `id` = '$pic_id'";
```

Comment: Security note: using MySQL query like that is prone to SQL-injection. Highly discouraged in production environment of your system ;)

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in your php script. Please dont use `mysql_query`. Use `PDO`.

```
$pic_id = (int) $_REQUEST['id'];

$db = new PDO("...");
$q = $db->prepare("SELECT points FROM `photos` WHERE `id` = :pic_id");
$q->bindValue(':pic_id', $pic_id);
$q->execute();

if ($q->rowCount() > 0){
    $check = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $points = $check['points'];
}else{
    $points = 0;
}

echo $points;
```

And then in your ajax function:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "rating.php",
    data: data,
    success: function(response) {

        if(response != 0) {
            var currentValue = response;
            var newValue = +currentValue - 1;
            $("#points_"+id).text(newValue);
        }

    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
    alert(errorThrown);
    } 
});
```